# Jinja2 Array Iteration Problems

Tags: python, csv, jinja2

I am getting some unusual behaviour with Jinja2 and iterating through an array which I can't quite put my finger on. I am passing a dictionary into Jinja2, one of the values of the dictionary is an array. A simple example of this works okay.

```
mydict = {
    'testvar1': 'this is a test var 1',
    'testvar2': 'this is a test var 2',
    'testvar3': ['test','test','test','test','test'],
    }
```

This is my Jinja template

```
{{ testvar1 }}
{{ testvar2 }}
{% for var in testvar3 %}
    {{ var }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now this actually works, I get the below output

```
this is a testvar1
this is a testvar2
test
test
test
test
test
test
```

However, I am generating a dictionary using the CSV import utility. Now I am aware that this tool imports all values as strings, so I am separating the 'array field' with dashes so I can split them later on.

```
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("./my_path/import.csv"))
for row in input_file:
    for key, value in row.iteritems():
        if '-' in value:
             value = value.split('-')
```

When I print both the array value from the dictionary created manually and the dictionary created by the csv import they look identical.

```
['test','test','test','test','test']
```

However when I generate the configuration using the dictonary populated by the csv import, the output I get is completely different.

```
testvar1
testvar2
t
e
s
t
t
e
s
t
```

And so forth...

Now it seems it is iterating over the values as if is were a simple string value, printing one character at a time for each iteration of the loop.

But it works perfectly when making the dictionary manually.

Any ideas? If there is a cleaner way to do this I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be unimportant, but why are the first two strings printed different in your two examples? First example says "this is a testvar1", but the second one just says "testvar1". Not trying to nitpick, just trying to understand how this output was generated.

Comment: Please show more of your python code.  Such as how you pass your variables to the render function.

Comment: you're not alone! i have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was I had the wrong JSON syntax in my database.

```
{
    "tags" : "[my, wrong, array]"
}
```

ended up beeing interpreted as unicode object from python which explains why iterating over it was iterating over every character.
the right syntax is:

```
{
    "tags": [
        "tech",
        "python",
        "flask"
    ]
}
```