# Problems when iterating thru an array of string returned by a Jinja2 macro called in DBT

Tags: arrays, jinja2, dbt

I encounter a problem when I'm trying to iterate thru an array of String created by a Jinja2 macro. The macro seems to correctly create the array of String (representing dates) and I'm able to see the correct value in DBT.
Unfortunately, when I iterate the array returned, it seems that the iteration is done on characters and not strings.

The call of the macro is here:

```
 {%- set recalculationDate = get_range_of_dates(true) -%}
```

The "select" in DBT is the following:

```
 select {{ recalculationDate }} from  {{ source('Test', 'Table_1') }}
```

The results are the following:

```
select 
    ['2023-02-07', '2023-02-08', '2023-02-09', '2023-02-10', '2023-02-11', '2023-02-12', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-14', '2023-02-15', '2023-02-16', '2023-02-17', '2023-02-18', '2023-02-19', '2023-02-20'] from Table_1
```

The problem is when I try to iterate this array with the following code in DBT :

```
    {%- for currentDate in recalculationDate -%}
        select {{ currentDate }} from  {{ source('Test', 'Table_1') }}
    {%- endfor -%}
```

I have these results:

```
  select   from  Table_1  
  select   from  Table_1
  select   from  Table_1
  select   from  Table_1
  select   from  Table_1
  select [ from  Table_1
  select ' from  Table_1
  select 2 from  Table_1
  select 0 from  Table_1
  select 2 from  Table_1
  select 3 from  Table_1
  select - from  Table_1
  select 0 from  Table_1
  select 2 from  Table_1
  select - from  Table_1
  select 0 from  Table_1
  select 7 from  Table_1
  select ' from  Table_1
  select , from  Table_1
  select   from  Table_1
  select ' from  Table_1
and so on...
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem ? I'm also opened to hear a best coding for this case.
Regards.

Edits based on comments:

Final results expected (again, UNION ALL will be added later, for this example, consider that we just want multiple SELECT without UNION ALL clause:

```
Select "2023-02-07" from Table_1
Union All
Select "2023-02-08" from Table_1
Union All
Select "2023-02-09" from Table_1
...
```

The iteration will be done in DBT with the "for" described above.

Edit #2:
I have exactly the same problem as described in this questions:
[Jinja2 Array Iteration Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683101/jinja2-array-iteration-problems?rq=1)

Edit #3: To give more information, my problem is why "currentdate" (in the snippet below) return a character instead of a date as I returned an array of dates with my function ? (To be noted that this snippet is used as a test to look at the value of "currentDate" and that the code in final version will have the "currentdate" value in the WHERE clause, in addition to a "UNION ALL" part).
When printing the array received, we can see that this is really an array of dates separated by comma.

```
    {%- for currentDate in recalculationDate -%}
        select {{ currentDate }} from  {{ source('Test', 'Table_1') }}
    {%- endfor -%}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the code?

Comment: The goal of the code is to create an array of dates with a Jinja macro, accept this array of dates in DBT and loop for each date with a SELECT in DBT. We want to replicate a "rewind", a reload of data (historical data, images of a day) for days in the past.

Comment: Still don't understand it. Could you provide an example of the compiled SQL you would be willing to get?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand either, but I THINK you're trying to use the results of a query inside your Jinja context. If so, you need to use `run_query` (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query)

Comment: @Aleix CC : I edit the questions and describe the results expected

Comment: @ Adam Kipnis: No, I just want to use a Jinja macro to generate a range of dates in an array and returned this array of dates to a SQL/Jinja query in DBT where I will loop with a "for" loop to do a "select" with a "where" having each date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the macro (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75497633/how-to-create-a-range-of-dates-in-an-array-macro) and pasted below for reference) is important...

```
{%- macro get_range_of_dates() -%}
{# Create an empty array to keep all dates #}
{%- set datesArray = [] -%}
{# Create a date representing the starting date of the range from a variable defined in dbt_project.yml  #}
{%- set start = modules.datetime.datetime.strptime(var("currentDate"), "%Y-%m-%d") -%}
{# Create a date reprsenting the ending date of the range (always currentDay) #}
{%- set end = modules.datetime.datetime.now() -%}

{# If start and end variables are not empty...#}
{%- if start and end -%}
    {# Calculate the lenght of the range #}
    {%- set duration = (end - start).days + 1 -%}
    {# Loop the range #}
    {%- for day in range(0, duration) -%}
        {# Add one day at each iteration #}
        {%- set dateIterated = (start + modules.datetime.timedelta(day)) -%}
        {# Convert datetime to string with the desired format #}
        {%- set finalDate = dateIterated.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") -%}
        {# Append the new date to the array of dates #}
        {%- do datesArray.append(finalDate) -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%}
{# return the array of dates #}
{{ datesArray }}
{%- endmacro -%}
```

The issue is that your macro is outputting the `datesArray` as a string and not returning it as an array so it can be used in the Jinja context. Change `{{ datesArray}}` at the bottom to `{{ return(datesArray) }}` and you will get the result you're expecting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and the time spent on this, it works very well. With your explanation, I understand now. Thanks again.